# Why after generating a signed APK release do I still receive INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES during development?

Tags: android, android-signing

**My Problem:**

I'm still receiving the ***INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES*** error after creating the necessary keystore, key and signing my application. This error initially occurred after updating the `minSdkVersion` version to 24 for needed functionality, but it still occurs after completing the resolution. I'm not sure why exactly.

**What I have done:**

I have followed the wizard procedures (see links below) for creating a signed release of my app currently in development, creating the keystore, key, password, signing the app, etc, etc. I've read a number of posts here but nothing appears to address my issue specifically - that I have found so far. Only how resolve the initial reason for the error -- not having a signed app.

What haven't I done is the Google Play app signing. I didn't think this was necessary until I'm ready to move the app there and I may not actually ever offer it there.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated as my app development is now dead in the water until I resolve this issue.

I followed all the steps here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing  - Steps 1 and 2 specific to signing your app.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extracting-a-signed-android-package.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. My emulator device version was not compatible. Once I setup a new emulator device meeting the minimum version, the app began to install successfully. So increasing the `minSdkVersion` caused my emulator device to be incompatible.